# generate variable conditional on other observation with common identifier

Tags: r, stata, survey

I am trying to link an individual with their parent using survey data. Specifically, I have data on whether or not an individual has a degree or not. I want to create an indicator variable equal to one if the parent has a degree. I have a family identifier variable and a variable for whether the individual is a parent or a child.

If anyone could provide some advice on how I could do this, that would be appreciated. If you want to provide example code, I am experienced in R and Stata.

Edit:

I have something like this:

```
Person Family Characteristic Degree
1        1     Child           No
2        1     Parent          Yes
3        2     Child           No
4        2     Parent          No
```

I want something like this:

```
Person Family Characteristic Degree Parent_Degree
1         1       Child        No         1
3         2       Child        No         0
```

Comment: Please provide few rows of sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in Stata:

```
clear 
input Person Family str9 Characteristic str3 Degree
1        1     Child           No
2        1     Parent          Yes
3        2     Child           No
4        2     Parent          No
end 

gen byte_Degree = (Degree=="Yes")
bys Family: egen Parent_Degree = total(byte_Degree)
* in case both parents have a degree
replace Parent_Degree = (Parent_Degree > 0)
drop byte_Degree Degree
keep if Characteristic == "Child"

list
     +---------------------------------------+
     | Person   Family   Charac~c   Parent~e |
     |---------------------------------------|
  1. |      1        1      Child          1 |
  2. |      3        2      Child          0 |
     +---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This could be slimmed down using `bys Family: egen Parent_Degree = max(Degree == "Yes")`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a R solution using the dplyr library:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%

  # within each family, let Parent_Degree be 1 if any parent has a degree
  group_by(Family) %>%
  mutate(Parent_Degree = as.integer(any(Characteristic == "Parent" & Degree == "Yes"))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # keep only child rows
  filter(Characteristic == "Child")

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Person Family Characteristic Degree Parent_Degree
   <int>  <int> <fctr>         <fctr>         <int>
1      1      1 Child          No                 1
2      3      2 Child          No                 0
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE,
                 text = "Person Family Characteristic Degree
                 1        1     Child           No
                 2        1     Parent          Yes
                 3        2     Child           No
                 4        2     Parent          No")
```